# passing a method as a constructor's parameter

Tags: c#, constructor

While I was looking at some c# code I found a new class declaration which had passed a method as a constructor’s parameter.This is my first time I have seen something like this and it has no meaning for me .Although the whole application works fine  I am still interested to know  what is the main idea behind the scene.

```
var c = new List<TheClass>
{
    new TheClass(TheMethod);
}

private void TheMethod()
{
    //do somthing
}
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: can we pass a method as a constructor's parameter ? and why should we do this ?

Comment: @T.shaped - yes you can and it depends on your scenario!

Comment: You do not pass method itself but `delegate` (which is like a pointer to the method). Delegates (often called *callbacks* from usage scenario) are very useful to make architecture more dynamic.

Comment: What's the syntax for passing in a Task

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the `TheClass` constructor accepts an [`Action` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class TheClass
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    public TheClass(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
}
```

This way `TheClass` can execute the provided action at a later time, and more than once.

For example:

```
public void DoAction()
{
    _action();
}
```

You could also do:

```
var theClass = new TheClass(() => TheMethod());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons that you might want to pass a method into the constructor of a class.

One of the most important is for so-called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), where want to inject a dependency into a class.

Suppose that a class needs to create an object. Normally, that class would do something like `var item = new MyConcreteClass();`.

However, that creates a strong dependency between the class creating the object and `MyConcreteClass`. This can make it harder to unit test or change implementations.

To circumvent this problem, you can do this:

1. Extract from `MyConcreteClass` an interface (say `IMyInterface`) which contains all the things you need to use from inside the class being written.
2. Pass to the class constructor a `Func` method which creates and returns a concrete class as `IMyInterface`.
3. Inside the class being written, call that `Func` to create the object rather than creating it directly using `new`.

The `Func` is therefore acting as a factory.

Code might look like this:

```
using System;

namespace Spacelabs.WcfDuplexDemo.Client
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass(() => new MyConcreteClass());

            myClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        string MyMethod(int param);
    }

    public sealed class MyConcreteClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public string MyMethod(int param)
        {
            return param.ToString();
        }
    }

    public sealed class MyClass
    {
        private readonly Func<IMyInterface> createMyInterface;

        public MyClass(Func<IMyInterface> createMyInterface)
        {
            this.createMyInterface = createMyInterface;
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // Instead of var item = new MyConcreteClass(), we do the following:

            var item = createMyInterface();
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyMethod(12345));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to defer execution of the method and control when it gets executed.

One use case for this is passing a method that creates and object so that the class controls when the object is created and it can control how many times it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unclear of why a method is being passed as an argument or specificly as an argument in a constructor?

CodeCaster already spoke short about Action delegates and if you're interested in storing methods in delegates like Action, I suggest you read up on Delegates [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

I'd like to provide a short example of a class that contains an Action delegate: RelayCommand -> I've illustrated the use of this delegate with the MVVM pattern below:

```
class ViewModelDefault : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TextProperty { get; set;}

    public ICommand ButtonProperty 
    { 
        get {
            RelayCommand relayCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteCommand); 
            return relayCommand; 
        } 
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand() 
    {
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        handler.SaveTextInTextfile(TextboxProperty);
    }

    ...
}
```

In the `MVVM` pattern, your main focus is to seperate data, logic and view, which is why using `Delegate` is perfect in this scenario.

You'd normally want to bind a property such as a `string` from the `ViewModel` to a `View` UI Element such as a `TextBox`.

Making use of delegates, allows you to bind a method (which would otherwise not be bindable to a UI element) through an Action property.

In the example above, the method ExecuteCommand is stored in an action field inside the RelayCommand object. This is bindable to a UI element, and will execute the method once it's requested.